# How do I install/enable OpenMP for Eclipse with MinGW on Windows?

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, mingw, openmp

As I continue my foray into learning C++, I'm trying to enable OpenMP in Eclipse (C/C++ Mars 4.5.0) using the MinGW toolchain.  Suffice it to say I have no idea how to go about it.  Adding the `-fopenmp` flag to the C/C++ compiler options in the project settings wasn't sufficient.  I attempted to compile and run the following test code provided by OpenMP using the GNU Make Builder:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

Eclipse spit out the following:

```
Building file: ../OpenMPTest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -MMD -MP -MF"OpenMPTest.d" -MT"OpenMPTest.d" -o "OpenMPTest.o" "../OpenMPTest.cpp"
../OpenMPTest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../OpenMPTest.cpp:14:23: error: expected '#pragma omp' clause before 'printf'
  #pragma omp parallel printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
                       ^
../OpenMPTest.cpp:15:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
 }
 ^
make: *** [OpenMPTest.o] Error 1
```

That gives me the (possibly incorrect) impression that Eclipse can't find the OpenMP libraries.

So, before I screw anything up beyond repair, I was wondering if I could get a step-by-step for-idiots guide to installing and enabling OpenMP in an Eclipse project with MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

Don't place anything on the `#pragma` line that is not supposed to be there.
The `#pragma` lines are instructions for the preprocessor and your `printf` code should not be there.

Your `main()` should look like

```
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }
    return 0;
}
```